# how do i dynamically allot names to the buttons from database in android?

Tags: android, database

this is my main xml file....i need to dynamically allot names to the 4 buttons...how can i do it??
the four buttons that need to be named dynamically are
UpperLeft
UpperRight
LowerLeft
LowerRight

```
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/UpperLeft"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="5dp"/>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/UpperRight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="5dp"/>


</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/LowerLeft"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="5dp"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/LowerRight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="5dp"
        />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:gravity="center"

    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:text="@string/answer"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
```

this is my main xml file....i need to dynamically allot names to the 4 buttons from the database...how can i do it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it from Java.

```
button.setText("button name");
```

Comment: Simply get the names from Database and set it to the button. [Here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm) is a tutorial on Android SQLite Database.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use this after initialize your `Button` Views.

```
yourbutton1.setText("Button1");
yourbutton2.setText("Button2");
yourbutton3.setText("Button3");
yourbutton4.setText("Button4");
```